# Lower voltage limit of constant current driver

Tags: led-driver, constant-current

I am looking for a constant current driver with rather low current (100-200mA) to drive COB LEDs (approx 34V). I found several which give an output voltage range, e.g.

12 W
input: 220 Vac 50 Hz
output: 90-102 Vdc 115 mA

Will that one really not work if the load has a voltage drop of only 34@115 mA or will the efficiency be low but work anyway?

Comment: Put a 10 watt, 510 ohm resistor in series with your LEDs, to increase the voltage drop into your driver's (rather small) target window. Too low an output voltage may in the best case cause it to shut down, thinking it's been short-circuited. In the worst case, it may release smoke.

Comment: Buy a driver rated for the voltage you need. Do not try to use one designed for a much higher voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switchmode constant current regulator doesn't waste energy in the same scale as a series transistor constant current source would do. Think the switchmode current regulator as a modified buck type voltage regulator which is modified to keep the coil (and load) current in predetermined limits. The switch is ON causes current to gradually increase and the current decreases when the switch is OFF. The coil current continues through the diode when the switch is OFF.

[image]

I do not believe a commercial switchmode current regulator works if it's used with a load which has different voltage drop than what's specified. Nobody guarantees anything if a device is used out of its specs. If it's designed as a current controlling buck regulator, the current in the coil grows fast at low output voltage - remember the induction law di/dt = U/L. The regulation may be poor and the switch transistor or mosfet may get too hot if it's not designed to turn its state fast enough.

BTW. I guess it's in practice impossible to make the above circuit so that the input voltage is rectified 230VAC, the output is about 34V at the wanted current and the current swing really happens so slowly that the device is not a remarkable radio noise transmitter. The inductor for that purpose should be far too big to be practical. If one allows the current to be triangle Ipeak =200mA with rise time from 0 to 200 mA say 20 us, inductor could be 29 millihenries which is still quite a boulder. 10 times higher operating frequency needs only 2,9 mH, but people who try to use AM radios in the neighbourhood surely would have something to say.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a linear regulator, it will deliver 34*0.115 = 4 W to the load (LEDs), and dissipate ~ 8 W internally which is inefficient, and perhaps above its internal power dissipation capability.

For a more qualified answer, you need the specs for the driver.